# Laravel 5.1 Route groups

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following `Route::group` setup in my `routes.php` file.  The problem is that I now want to add a new route `Route::post('/timesheets/new', 'Timesheet\TimesheetController@create');` but the problem is the controller is located in a different directory and therefore, the namespace on the group is causing Laravel to look for the controller in the same directory.

**My Route::group**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function ()
{
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');
    Route::get('/contractors', 'ContractorController@index');

});
```

**I want to add this:**

```
Route::get('/timesheets/new', 'Timesheet\TimesheetController@index');
```

However, when I do this, I get the error:

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Timesheet\TimesheetController does not exist
```

Comment: Should it have the prefix admin?

Comment: Yes the prefix admin is correct.  However I want the admin user to have access to the TimesheetController which is located in Controllers/Timesheet

Comment: You need to create another group with another namespace and put the route there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', ], function ()
{
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {
        Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');
        Route::get('/contractors', 'ContractorController@index');
    });

    Route::get('/timesheets/new', 'Timesheet\TimesheetController@index');
});
```